# Change, override, replace, asp.net MVC 3 default DataAnnotations Validations messages for required and invalid values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I have:

```
public class StudentDto
{
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    public DateTime? Born { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using jQuery `datepicker`, and whenever I put an invalid data, the validation message is: Please enter a valid date.

How can i change this default message?

I've already tried using:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = @"Valor inválido")]
```

I've already tried to create a `.resx`, and use `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Strings";` , and on my `.resx`  created values for: `InvalidPropertyValue`, `Common_ValueNotValidForProperty`, `PropertyValueInvalid`

None of these worked.

Thanks!

## Update: I'm using Unobtrusive validation too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

Model:

```
public class StudentDto
{
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Some custom message for required date")]  
    public DateTime? Born { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new StudentDto());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StudentDto dto)
    {
        return View(dto);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Born').datepicker();
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Born)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Born)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Born)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

`Application_Start` in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Strings";
}
```

and inside `~/App_GlobalResources/Strings.resx` define the key `PropertyValueInvalid` which will be used if an invalid date is entered. For the value you could use the `{0}` and `{1}` placeholders which will be replaced respectively by the value and the display name of the field.

Comment: I cant understand... The required message works fine, but the Invalid data don't! I've done exactly the same thing as you told =/

Comment: @Renanlf, I created a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project from scratch and put the code you see in my answer at the correct locations. I've just referenced the `jquery-ui.js` in the _Layout for the datepicker to work. So what did you do differently than me if it doesn't work for you? Want me to send you a working copy of my project?

Comment: Maybe my problem is with the unobtrusive ajax thing! Does your code work with unobtrusive??

Comment: @Renanlf, unobtrusive what? Validation? Ajax?

Comment: Yeah! <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" /></appSettings>, and    jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

Comment: @Renanlf, maybe you could provide a concise and yet complete example of your code allowing to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Strings";` for binding validation ([forums.asp.net/post/3607981.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/post/3607981.aspx)) and `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Strings";` for unobtrusive validation.

`Strings` - name of resource file located in `App_GlobalResources` folder (`~/App_GlobalResources/Strings.resx`).